Expectation question of rolling fair dice

Athletes are competing by throwing a fair die, one after the other. All the dice throws are independent. The random variable $N$ (with  $N \geq 2$) is defined as the number of competitor who, for the first time, gets a result that is greater than or equal to the first competitor's result. What is $\mathbb{E}[N]$?

My Attempt:
If $\mathbb{P}(Y\geq x)=\sum \mathbb{P}(Y\geq i) \cdot \mathbb{P}(i) =7/12$, I derived that:
$$\mathbb{P}(N=k)=\frac{7}{12} \left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^{k-2}.$$
Using this, I tried to calculate the expected value $\mathbb{E}[N]
as:
$$\mathbb{E}[N] = \sum k \cdot \frac{7}{12} \left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^{k-2}.$$
Simplifying this, I obtained
$$\mathbb{E}[N] = \frac{19}{7}.$$
However, I know that the formal answer should be $\dfrac{69}{20}$.
​
What did I do wrong in my calculations?

Welcome on MSE. You're supposed to show the work you've done so far so we can try to help you!

You take a fixed probability for the chance of rolling higher than the first person, but you cannot do that. The first person has six different options to roll, and the expectation of $N$ depends heavily on the first roll. As a hint for how to do it correctly: try using that $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$ (if that does not ring a bell: look up conditioning).

Hint: suppose the first roll is a 6. What is the expected value of $N$ you need in this case?
Now do the same for every other possible value of the first roll, and average the results. This works since $E[N]=\sum_k P(K=k)E[N\mid K=k]$, where the sum is taken over possible values of the discrete random variable $K$. (Here $K$ is the first roll.)
